# What is this part? A958 960L

Tags: audio, voltage-regulator, components, receiver

I have an optimus STAV 3200 ([radioshack parts link](http://support.radioshack.com/support_audio/doc22/22776.htm)) and this component labeled A958 960L blew itself in two taking a resistor with it. The parts list does not specify what the component is or what I would need to replace it with. Any help would be very much appreciated.
On the board it is labeled as Q519R. The resistor (R549R) is 180ohm 5% 1/5w I believe based on the parts list, would you agree?[image: Circuit plus front plate that was blown off]
If I replace the resistor and what ever part this is, do you believe that will be it or is this likely caused by the failure of a different component? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is a PNP power transistor, a Japanese part number. There is an implied '2S' in front.

Here is a datasheet:http://datasheet.eeworld.com.cn/pdf/SAVANTIC/266368_2SA957.pdf

Chances are other parts have been damaged.